# beautifulsoup getting text between tag

Tags: html, parsing, beautifulsoup

```
   date =soup.find_all("td", {"id": "utime"})
   print date

 [<td class="mstat-date" colspan="3" id="utime">23.11.2015 17:00</td>]
```

this is what i want
[23.11.2015 17:00]

```
      print(soup.date.string)
     AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

Little help please, thank you.

Comment: Clean up your code before asking a question(!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The method `find_all` will always return a list. In a list, you must index, before you can access methods on the elements contained within. So when you have

   ```
   date =soup.find_all("td", {"id": "utime"})
   ```

   You can access the text from the first tag, by typing:

   ```
   date[0].text
   ```

   If there are more items in the list, you can use a list comprehension, like this:

   ```
   [ _.text for _ in date ]
   ```

   That will give you a list of dates, if the HTML you're scraping had more than one such date-like tags.
2. Your beautifulsoup instance will not have associated with it a `date` attribute/property, unless in some very specific conditions. Use your first function to access all the dates, so don't try this approach (bad: `soup.date`).